# Is Failover Clustering imlpementable within a Hyper-V

Tags: sql-server, cluster-computing, windows-server-2012, failover, hyper-v

I am currently under the following Scenario.

My Company is trying to implement Failover Clustering for it's Databases on SQL Server.

and before that I am supposed to test the implementation on a Virtual Machine.

**My question**: Is this Possible, can I fully Implement Failover Clustering within a Hyper-V Machine ?
 can i build my way in it up to the desired result which is having 2 running Nodes, which step in for each other in case one database becomes unavailable ?

Here is the MSDN Configuration Link I've seen:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj822357.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can... but you shouldn't. Typically, the reason for needing a failover server is hardware-related failure. If you are running both Hyper-V servers on the same physical box, you have an 80% chance that your hardware failure will affect both virtual servers.

Comment: ...but if you read the whole question, you'll see they just want to know whether they can do this on a test system as a proof of concept, not in production.

Comment: Yes you can test it. Works great as a test since you can stop the main server ANYTIME you want without really breaking stuff.